# Prove that $S_i<1$ for all $i$ by induction

Tags: summation, induction

We define $x_1=\frac12$, and $x_n=(1-\frac{3}{2n})\cdot x_{n-1}$

Then we define $S_i=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_i$

Prove that $S_i<1$ for all $i$

I can see that $x_n=(1-\frac{3}{2n})\cdot (1-\frac{3}{2n-2})\cdots (1-\frac 34)\cdot \frac12$

But what then? I suppose my observation isn't useful though...

Comment: by finding reccurence equation solution, this WA computation may be useful: (1) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x(n)%3D(1-(3%2F(2n)))x(n-1),+x(1)%3D1%2F2 (2) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+(Pochhammer(1%2F2,+-1+%2B+n))%2F(2+%CE%93(1+%2B+n))+from+1+to+k (3) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1+%2B+k)+%CE%93(1%2F2+%2B+k))%2F(sqrt(%CF%80)+%CE%93(2+%2B+k))

Comment: It seems that $S=1$. See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B1000000%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cbinom%7B2n-2%7D%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7B2n%5Ccdot4%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help to observe,
\begin{align*}
x_n &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2n - 3}{2n} \cdot \frac{2n - 5}{2n - 2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{1}{4} \\
&= \frac{(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \ldots 1}{(2n)(2n - 2)(2n - 4) \ldots 2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n n!}(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \ldots 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n n!} \cdot \frac{(2n - 2)(2n - 3)(2n - 4) \ldots 1}{(2n - 2)(2n - 4) \ldots 2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n n!} \cdot \frac{(2n - 2)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n - 2)!}{2 \cdot 4^{n-1} n ((n - 1)!)^2} \\
&= \frac{\binom{2n - 2}{n - 1}}{n 2^{2n-1}} \\
&= \frac{C(n - 1)}{2^{2n - 1}},
\end{align*}
where $C(n)$ is the $n$th [Catalan number.](https://oeis.org/A000108) According to [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Proof_of_the_formula) the Catalan numbers have the following generating function:
$$c(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.$$
With any luck, we should have,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = \frac{1}{2}c\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 1,$$
provided the Maclaurin Series converges (removing the removable discontinuity at $0$) where we want. Unfortunately, this value lies right on the boundary of the radius of convergence, but it does mean that this sum equalling $1$ is equivalent to  the Maclaurin series of $\sqrt{1 - x}$ converging to $0$ at $x = 1$. It seems like a more elementary problem, but I don't personally have a proof that it's true.

Comment: I'm looking for a good upper bound for $\binom {2n}n$, but I can't find any.

Comment: Using this and the bound $\binom{2n}n\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ I have found that $x_n\le\frac 1{2n\sqrt{3n-2}}$. This shows that $S_n$ converges.

Comment: If Michael Rozenberg's suspicion is right, and the series does sum to $1$, these kinds of bounds won't help us show the partial sums are less than $1$. Maybe there's some kind of a combinatorial argument, and we can formulate the series as a sum of probabilities of mutually exclusive events?